# Persistent grub rescue following successful operation

Tags: grubrescue

I've successfully installed Ubuntu 14.04 on an Asus eeepc netbook. It works fine for a day or two then on boot up I get the message:

```
Attempt to read or write outside of disc 'hd0'. 
Entering rescue mode. Grub rescue
```

I've reinstalled it several times with the same result each time. I've followed several suggestions all ending in `insmod normal` but it always returns the same message. What is strange is that after a fresh install it will shutdown and boot up fine a few times before giving up.

I'd be extremely grateful if anyone has a solution to this. Thanks

Comment: I think you must have created your partitions wrongly. Did you use _manual_ or _auto_ settings to create them.

Comment: Thanks George -  I used auto settings. I suspected faulty partitioning but that area was a foreign land to me, so I was hesitant to go there.  However, I found some help online, bit the bullet and created some partitions and it seems to have worked. Just this minute updated the software.   I think it might be a little slower to boot than it was when I dual booted some time ago, but I can live with that.  It may well prompt me to explore the command prompt.  Thanks again for your help and editing of the question.

Comment: Sure thing glad it worked out :).